# What is this species of angiosperm from Morocco?

Tags: species-identification, botany

The flowers are about 1 cm long. The plant is about 1 metre high. Photographed in spring. The plant was found in a ruderal environment. [image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks a bit like a Flax relative, genus *Linum*, but the hairy leaves and stems aren't consistent with *Linum usitatissimum* which is the flax of commerce (the textile linen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the [*Symphytum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphytum) genus, or related genera within Boraginaceae (the forget-me-not family). It is loosely similar to [*Symphytum officinale*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphytum_officinale), but clearly not that species. The overall layout, size, leaves and hairyness of the stalks is similar to species in *Symphytum*.

Here is *Symphytum officinale*, as an example of the overall appearance:

[image]

Also similar from the *Anchusa* genus in the same family (*Anchusa azurea*):

[image]

Comment: For the record; I don't really think this answer deserves the "accepted" badge.

Comment: I agree with Borraginaceae. The examples you provide could be close, but the leaves seem a bit different.